# python file reading

Tags: python, file, string

I have file /tmp/gs.pid with content

```
client01: 25778
```

I would like retrieve the second word from it.
ie. `25778`.

I have tried below code but it didn't work.

```
>>> f=open ("/tmp/gs.pid","r")
>>> for line in f:
    ...   word=line.strip().lower()
    ...   print "\n -->" , word
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> f = open("/tmp/gs.pid", "r")
>>> for line in f:
    ...   word = line.strip().split()[1].lower()
    ...   print " -->", word
>>> f.close()
```

It will print the second word of every line in lowercase. `split()` will take your line and split it on any whitespace and return a list, then indexing with `[1]` will take the *second* element of the list and `lower()` will convert the result to lowercase. Note that it would make sense to check whether there are at least 2 words on the line, for example:

```
>>> f = open("/tmp/gs.pid", "r")
>>> for line in f:
    ...   words = line.strip().split()
    ...   if len(words) >= 2:
    ...      print " -->", words[1].lower()
    ...   else:
    ...      print 'Line contains fewer than 2 words.'
>>> f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

If all lines are of the form `abc: def`, you can extract the 2nd part with

```
second_part = line[line.find(": ")+2:]
```

If not you need to verify `line.find(": ")` really returns a nonnegative number first.

```
with open("/tmp/gs.pid") as f:
   for line in f:
      p = line.find(": ")
      if p != -1:
        second_part = line[p+2:].lower()
        print "\n -->", second_part
```

Comment: The `find()` check could be simplified as `if ': ' in line:`, though you'll need to split rather than use the find index in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
word="client01: 25778"
pid=word.split(": ")[1] #or word.split()[1] to split from the separator
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> open("/tmp/gs.pid").read().split()[1]
'25778'
```